# Chromebook can't download to Google Drive because Hard Disk is full?

Tags: hard-drive, google-chrome, download, chromebook, google-chrome-os

I recently had to powerwash my Chromebook to fix a keyboard issue I was having and all my files were deleted as a result.  I have downloaded 18GB of files to google drive on my chromebook, and only 268MB of Downloads and Browsing data to the hard drive.  The google drive files are not set to be available offline, but are anyways.  My chromebook says that I only have 491MB of space left on the hard drive, and I can't download a 200MB file to my google drive (even though literal terabytes of data remain).  The chromebook is heavily locked down by my Administrator (who provided the chromebook), so I can't access some critical parts of the settings, but I absolutely cannot figure out why I can't download things to my google drive anymore.  I've tried clearing up space but that fixes nothing.  I'm afraid that when I powerwashed it, the files weren't actually deleted but aren't able to be seen by the file explorer.  If this is the case, I don't want to reset it again.  I can't even save screenshots to show what's happening.  There is a recent section in the file explorer which is read-only that shows several GB of data, but I think it's just a display of recent files and not a storage place.

How do I fix this?  It's basically rendering my chromebook useless for my purposes.

Comment: Speak to your Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've described, if I were in your situation, unfortunately I would ask my administrator. Without administrator access, I am not sure what other avenues are available